# Bash quoting paranoid or necessary

Tags: bash, security, quoting

I wanted to know how vulnerable is bash by code injection. So I wrote a script as simple as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep $1 $2
```

and saved it as `greptest.sh`. The quotes around the variables were dropped intentionally for vulnerability test, so `grep "$1" "$2"` is the preferred way.
Then I created `test.txt`:

```
sadhuer
sadjfh Hello
cusad
Hello
fgdfg
```

First was to show its proper use.

```
$ ./greptest.sh 'Hello' 'test.txt'
```

Output as expected:

```
sadjfh Hello
Hello
```

Then the first attack:

```
$ ./greptest.sh 'Hello test.txt'
```

Outputs the same as above. So, obviously, it does something due to missing quotes within the script - altough $2 is empty! Next try with $2 not empty for proving my assumption that $2 will be interpreted as a further input file:

```
$ ./greptest.sh 'Hello test.txt' 'nonexistingfile.txt'
```

outputs:

```
test.txt:sadjfh Hello
test.txt:Hello
grep: nonexistingfile.txt: No such file or directory
```

Then the harder attack: Trying to execute an arbitrary command:

```
$ ./greptest.sh 'Hello test.txt' '; ls'
```

outputs:

```
test.txt:sadjfh Hello
test.txt:Hello
grep: ;: No such file or directory
grep: ls: No such file or directory
```

I did not expect this. I thought the variables were subsitituted to yield

```
grep Hello test.txt ; ls
```

which should result in listing the current directory. So, is missing these quotes just ugly and error prone or a serious security concern I should care about (given the values of these parameters come from an untrusted source)?

Comment: In case of `grep $1 $2`, I don't see a security concern. But, if later in the script `$var` contains a command name, or `eval` is involved, you're in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `eval`, which is always very special about security. Of course, I could even write `eval grep $1 $2`, then my execution of `ls` really works.

Comment: Unless you're executing a variable, I don't see how code injection enters the picture. Quoting is still necessary if you don't want unintended effects: `cp $1 $2`, for example. Quoting and security is extensively discussed on [unix.se]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/70524

Comment: Semicolons as command separators are recognized *before* parameter expansion, so any semicolons resulting from expansion are treated as literal text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the parameters passed to your greptest.sh bash script, as you are passing the parameters directly as parameters to the called program (grep in this case).

You need to worry about whatever calls greptest.sh injecting parameters onto *that* command line.

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82643/67045) for information.

Answer (score 0):

1. One security issue of unquoted variables (though not code injection) is *glob expansion DoS* – a variable without quotes not only undergoes word splitting, but also globbing!

   If the variable contains a pattern like `*/*/../../` repeated several times, like `*/*/../../*/*/../../`, `*/*/../../*/*/../../*/*/../../` and so on, then the number of files that expands to increases exponentially with the length of the pattern.
2. Not related to quoting, but if the attacker can influence $PATH, $LD_PRELOAD, etc, then he can make `grep` in your script mean anything.